# Callback from page Javascript to Extension

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon-webextensions

Hey guys I am trying to make an extension for GeckoView, but I need to get a value from the page to the Android app. So I followed [this guide for native messaging](https://firefox-source-docs.mozilla.org/mobile/android/geckoview/consumer/web-extensions.html), and I can send a message to my app. But what I need is to get a value from the page and send it to my app. I get the value from a callback of a function I loaded onto the page by injecting  tags, but since the function is then on the page, I can't access the browser.runtime.sendNativeMessage("browser", ticket);

```
script.innerText = `
                function myCallback(ticket) {
                    browser.runtime.sendNativeMessage("browser", ticket);
                }`
```

This function when called will just throw a

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: browser is not defined
```

So is there any nice way to get a value from a callback on the page Javascript to the extension Javascript and thus to the app?

Comment: 1) In Firefox you don't need to use a `<script>` to get values from page: you can get them directly like `window.wrappedJSObject.foo`. It means you can keep the entire code inside the content script. Except for sendNativeMessage: native messaging cannot directly be used in content scripts. You must do it indirectly via background scripts. 2) If you still want to use a script then use standard DOM messaging via CustomEvent to content script, which will call the background script which will call the native host.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know you could just use window.wrappedJSObject. Since it's for Android I solved it by sending an alert() and just overwriting the onAlert Listener. Btw you can send native messages from content scripts, like shown in the link in the post, you just need special permission